# R- Creating the same alluvial order in multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the ggalluvial package to make multiple alluvial plots for some data that I have, but I'd like to try to order the alluvials so I can compare them across multiple plots.

Here's some example data:

```
set.seed(234)

Data1 <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:10, each = 6),
  Group = rep(1:2, each = 30),
  Week = rep(1:6, times = 10),
  Y = sample(c("High", "Low", "None"), 60, replace = TRUE)
)

Data2 <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:10, each = 6),
  Group = rep(1:2, each = 30),
  Week = rep(1:6, times = 10),
  Y = sample(c("High", "Low", "None"), 60, replace = TRUE)
)
```

And some example code for making the two graphs:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(Data1,
       aes(x = Week, 
           stratum = Y, 
           alluvium = ID,
           fill = Y,
           label = Y))+
  facet_grid(Group ~.)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "yellow", "green3"))+
  geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "frontback", color = "darkgray")+
  geom_stratum()

plot2 <- ggplot(Data2,
       aes(x = Week, 
           stratum = Y, 
           alluvium = ID,
           fill = Y,
           label = Y))+
  facet_grid(Group ~.)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "yellow", "green3"))+
  geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "frontback", color = "darkgray")+
  geom_stratum()
```

And finally the two output graphs
[image: Plot1]
[image: Plot2]

Is there a way to know which alluvial belongs to which individual? Or designate the order of alluvials so that, for example, the top group 1 alluvial is the same in the first and second graphs? I realize that might make the graph look kind of bad, but for my actual data the outcome in the first week is pretty homogenous across the board so I think it would be alright.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that makes the most sense to me at this point is to pass the `alluvium` variable (in this case, `ID`) to the `label` aesthetic in a new layer using the alluvium stat and the text geom. Provided the parameters (e.g. `lode.guidance`) are passed the same values, the new layer should stack the alluvia in the same order at every axis, and the text labels will coincide with the "lodes" where the alluvia intersect the strata.

Here are your examples with the additional layer. Note that it is added *after* the stratum layer; otherwise the text would be obscured by the filled-in rectangles.

```r
library(ggalluvial)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

set.seed(234)

Data1 <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:10, each = 6),
  Group = rep(1:2, each = 30),
  Week = rep(1:6, times = 10),
  Y = sample(c("High", "Low", "None"), 60, replace = TRUE)
)

Data2 <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:10, each = 6),
  Group = rep(1:2, each = 30),
  Week = rep(1:6, times = 10),
  Y = sample(c("High", "Low", "None"), 60, replace = TRUE)
)

ggplot(Data1,
       aes(x = Week, 
           stratum = Y, 
           alluvium = ID,
           fill = Y,
           label = Y))+
  facet_grid(Group ~.)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "yellow", "green3"))+
  geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "frontback", color = "darkgray")+
  geom_stratum()+
  geom_text(stat = "alluvium", aes(label = ID), lode.guidance = "frontback")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(Data2,
       aes(x = Week, 
           stratum = Y, 
           alluvium = ID,
           fill = Y,
           label = Y))+
  facet_grid(Group ~.)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "yellow", "green3"))+
  geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "frontback", color = "darkgray")+
  geom_stratum()+
  geom_text(stat = "alluvium", aes(label = ID), lode.guidance = "frontback")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>